# calculating new measures in SSAS

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, business-intelligence

I have a cube in my sql server analysis service (2012) project. One of my measures is withdrawn money from ATM. Now I want to have a new calculated measure that show me the growth of withdrawn money today toward to last day. It is a dynamic calculated measure.
Is there any solution for doing this work?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is most probably called a KPI = key performance indicator. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174538%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) for information about how to add the metric you need.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show growth based on last value, for example today I Withdrew 10% less than yesterday, yo ucan use KIPs

if you want to show how much you Withdrew so far, you should use calculatins like YTD (year to date)

Answer (score 1):

You should use KPI to build your measure.

Open your SSAS project in Visual Studio and double click on your cube.
In the KPI tab there is a panel with some samples of KPI using parallel periods.

This is an example to create an operating margin accross two periods :

```
IIf
( 
  KPIValue( "Gross Profit Margin" ) >
  ( KPIValue( "Gross Profit Margin" ),
    ParallelPeriod
    ( 
       [<<Time Dimension Name>>].[<<Time Hierarchy Name>>].[<<Time Year Level Name>>],
       1,
       [<<Time Dimension Name>>].[<<Time Hierarchy Name>>].CurrentMember
    )
  ), 1, -1
)
```